# Company mode popup closes after C-n

Tags: company-mode

Company-mode gives me a popup with options, but once I press C-n to navigate through the options, the popup disappears (I can still cycle through the options , but they are shown inline). I want the popup to remain open until I make my selection. Is this a customizable behavior (for instance, [this screencast](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HKF41ivkBb0) shows a company-mode popup which remains open while he cycles through values)?

Could some other mode be interfering and closing the popup (e.g., evil-mode)? How would I go about debugging that (I'm new to emacs)? Thanks!

Comment: Unless you have changed settings, I believe company uses `M-n` (Alt-n) to cycle through options.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`company-mode` does not rebind <kbd>C-n</kbd> or <kbd>C-p</kbd> probably to minimize interference with normal editing commands. To cycle through options, Company uses <kbd>up</kbd>, <kbd>down</kbd>, <kbd>M-n</kbd>, and <kbd>M-p</kbd> by default.

Use <kbd>C-h f</kbd> `company-mode` to peruse the mode specific documentation for Company. It will show the available bindings for the company popup when it is active.

However if you do want <kbd>C-n</kbd> and <kbd>C-p</kbd> in addition to the existing bindings the following elisp should help.

```
(define-key company-active-map (kbd "C-n") 'company-select-next-or-abort)
(define-key company-active-map (kbd "C-p") 'company-select-previous-or-abort)
```

Answer (score 3):

With `use-package`, this becomes:

```el
(use-package company
  :hook
  (after-init . global-company-mode)
  :bind (:map company-active-map
     ("C-n" . company-select-next-or-abort)
     ("C-p" . company-select-previous-or-abort)))
```